# Criteria api Restriction of foreign key

Tags: hibernate-criteria

i'm using Hibernate criteria api in my java ee app. I have two Agenda interface in witch i use jsf/primefaces schedule. the first one get data with the method findall() but the second one get data with the method findByCriteria(cri). in the cri variable i have to compare a foreign key with null value
like this:

```
Criterion cri= Restrictions.eq("demande",null);
listIntervention=interventionService.findByCriteria(cri);
```

this syntax it doesn't work 
can some one help me? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use Restrictions#isNull. That one is used for comparing of NULL values.

```
Criterion cri = Restrictions.isNull("demande");
```